# Extjs: Accessing Proprety Grid linked in a window

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to access a PropertyGrid of a created NewPerson window.

- NewPerson window is composed of a propertygrid and a toolbar.
- When a user fill in the propertygrid and hits 'Save' button, a new
  person should be created with the attributes present in the
  propertygrid.
- the problem is that a user should be able to create as many NewPerson windows as he needs, so how can I access the propertygrid of a window? Thanks.

**NewPerson Window View:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ui.NewPerson', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    height: 180,
    width: 524,
    resizable: false
,
    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },
    title: 'New Person',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'newpersontoolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom'
                }
            ],
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'newpersongrid'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

**NewPersonGrid View:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ui.NewPersonGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.property.Grid',

    border: 0,
    id: 'newpersongrid',
    forceFit: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            source: {
                'Property 1': 'String',
                'Property 2': true,
                'Property 3': '2012-02-20T19:22:06',
                'Property 4': 123
            },
            listeners: {
                afterlayout: {
                    fn: me.onPropertyAfterLayout,
                    scope: me
                }
            }
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onPropertyAfterLayout: function(abstractcontainer, layout, options) {
    }

});
```

**NewPersonToolbar View:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ui.NewPersonToolbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',


    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'savebutton'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

**SaveButton View:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ui.SaveButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',

    text: 'Save person',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    fn: me.onButtonClick,
                    scope: me
                }
            }
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onButtonClick: function(button, e, options) {
      // GRID = code here to access propertygrid
      Ext.create('MyApp.model.Person', Ext.encode(GRID.getSource()));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `MyApp.view.ui.NewPerson` is a component that contains both the property grid and a save button, it makes sense to put the logic that binds the two there:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ui.NewPerson', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

   ...

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'newpersontoolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom'
                }
            ],
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'newpersongrid'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);

        me.down('#savePersonButton').handler = function(button, e) {
          me.down('#newpersongrid').doSomething();
        }
    }

});
```

You will need to add `itemId = 'savePersonButton'` and `itemId = 'newpersongrid'` property to both your button and grid respectively (since it is not an `id` it can be used in many instances of component, but will be scoped to one container each time.